# scipy.stats.genextreme.pdf with p value >1

Tags: python, scipy

I am using scipy for statistical analysis. I met a ridiculous thing that

```
rv = stats.genextreme(0.068791125981,loc = 1.10391927683, scale=0.309718667005 )
rv.pdf(1)
```

The output is 1.0915857950098409

Anyone could help to explain? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected, but in general, a pdf can be above 1. It's the integral over the entire pdf that should be 1.

Comment: I am confused. From Wiki, it says: "The probability density function is nonnegative everywhere, and its integral over the entire space is equal to one." If the whole is equal to one, how can I expect pdf(x) >1?

Comment: An an extreme case, consider a Dirac Delta function. It's definitely larger than one for where it's not zero, and still the integral over the real axis is one.

Comment: or consider uniform distribution on interval [0, 0.5] which has pdf equal to 2 on the interval.

Comment: I see. so I should use 1-cdf(x) to get the p value, right? I want to get pvalues for the right tail.